# How can I use the REST API to Remove Hold on a Bill?

Tags: acumatica

I've created a bill using the REST API - but now I want to release it (which exists as an action) - but I'm assuming I have to remove the HOLD before I do that.  I don't see that as an action.  How would I go about doing that?  And if this topic exists somewhere in the documentation, please let me know - I haven't been able to find anything.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the Bills endpoint and add action to it.
You need to add a new action to the Actions node of the Bills endpoint in the extended Web Service Endpoint like below
[image]
Then you can use that action like the below:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost/Acumatica/entity/DefaultExt/22.200.001/Bill/ReleaseFromHold' 
--data-raw '{
   "Entity": {
    "Type": {"value":"Bill"},
    "ReferenceNbr":{"value":"003238"}
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the hold status is still defined using the hold field, you can achieve that result by passing the false value to the Hold field.

{{BaseUrl}}/entity/default/22.200.001/Bill

```
{
    "id": "589535fc-4a60-ed11-84a8-00e04cc71f57",
    "Hold": {"value": false}
}
```